# Android: Correct way to stop, unbind and completely remove NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, service

I have a NotificationListenerService that is started from the Manifest. The service works and is processing notifications. I want to be able to stop, unbind and remove (onDestroy called). Can someone provide a minimal example?

I've tried implementing ServiceConnection and unbind() and selfstop() but it still won't run onDestroy. I also tried to setup NotificationListenerService inline but couldn't figure out how to bind it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the [What's new with Notifications in Android N talk](https://youtu.be/6eFQbC5r17w?t=2221), a `NotificationListenerService` is bound to the system forever. Since they are always bound by the system, it will never be destroyed.

As of Android N, you'll be able to call `requestUnbind()` to stop listening and `NotificationListenerService.requestRebind()` to start again, but before that there is no specific way to cause the system to unbind from your `NotificationListenerService`.

You can, of course, disable the service entirely using code such as:

```
PackageManager pm  = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
     ".YourNotificationListenerService");
  pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Which will prevent the service from running entirely. Unfortunately this may have a side effect where the system temporarily blacklists your `NotificationListenerService` (as it repeatedly fails to bind to it), so should only be used if you are disabling it permanently/semi-permanently.